# Styled Component dropdown in side navbar is getting hidden behind main content

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to show dropdown in side navbar on hover in styled component. It is getting hidden behind homepage content.

code:

```
const NavbarDropdownContent = styled.div`
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 10;
background-color: white;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

`;

const NavbarDropdown = styled.div`
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
overflow: visible;
&:hover ${NavbarDropdownContent} {
display: block;
}
`;

<NavbarDropdown>
            <NavLink to="/dial" activeClassName="active">
              <NavIcon>
                <img src="/images/messaging.svg"></img>
              </NavIcon>
            </NavLink>
              <NavbarDropdownContent>
                <div>
                  <NavLink to="">Dropdown1</NavLink>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <NavLink to="">Dropdown1</NavLink>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <NavLink to="">Dropdown1</NavLink>
                </div>
              </NavbarDropdownContent>
          </NavbarDropdown>
```

I want result like this.

[image]

Comment: Your nab bar dropdown component has display none. Try changing it to block or flex

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?
`z-index: 99999`

Comment: Yes, i did that too.. but then too it's not working.